# Upgrade stuck at update manager versions details

Tags: upgrade, 12.10

I have been upgrading to 12.10 beta 1 but ran into a issue, it asked which version of update manager I would like to use but when I pressed details (D) for more info it got stuck at that screen and I don’t know how to get it updating again.

Here is the current terminal output

```
    100
+++ /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.dpkg-new       2012-08-08 15:39:07.000000000 +0100
@@ -14,4 +14,4 @@
 #           used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
 #           release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
 #           determine if a newer release is available.
-prompt=normal
+Prompt=normal
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
(END)
```

What can I do to get it started again? I now know I want to use the non LTS (12.10) update manager.

Comment: This really should have been reported as a bug on launchpad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, than type: `:q!` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks that got it going will accept in 5 mins when allowed